# PHP Output Buffering

Tags: php, output-buffering

What are the methods to turn on output buffering either within a PHP script or using and htaccess file?

I use the following method in an htaccess file in the root of my application:

```
php_value output_buffering On
php_value output_handler mb_output_handler
```

On one of my shared hosting accounts (linux hosting with PHP 5.2.x), the above yields a blank page. Tech support says they can't turn it on in the php.ini file but I can turn it on in my script...

`ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` also yields the same result. What can I do?

Comment: If you get blank pages, look into the `error.log`. Did you set an [output encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-output-handler.php) before activating the mb_output_handler?

Comment: @mario, no, i didn't know i had to. how can i do that?

Comment: If you want this deleted, please flag it for moderator attention (as I just did). Kindly, stop rolling this back, it just puts nonsense on our front page :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`.

`ob_start()` at the start of the script before any output (not even an empty space).

When u want to output use `ob_end_flush()`.

Comment: 2nd time ive seen this today.  You can turn on output buffering AFTER or BEFORE printing content.  It makes no difference. http://ideone.com/URuKl

Comment: Sure it makes a difference. If you print something without output buffering turned on, it will actually be output.

Comment: @klinky i was not trying to demonstrate ob, i was demonstrating that you can call it at any point, not just at the start before any output, as predrag.music stated.

Comment: @jw it makes a difference, but its not going to break it and not work, which seems like what he was implying.  I think people get it confused with calling the header function, because often people will use output buffer to make sure they can use the header function.

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP.ini file and ensure the Output Buffer is enabled.

After that, you can use `ob_start()` whenever you want to begin buffering and `ob_flush()` to flush the buffer whenever you want to stop buffering.

Comment: If you use cPanel (most hosts do), there is an option in there to change the php.ini configurations.

Comment: FYI Scott, I use hostmonster.com, which is shared hosting, and I can still edit my own php.ini file.

Comment: @justinl, i know what you mean, on most of my account i can do the same - not all however.

Comment: that's unfortunate :S  I'm not sure why those other methods aren't working for you